# React: Using `setState` with a function inside `componentWillReceiveProps`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Considering the following React Component snippet, I need to set a new component state based on the new props and the current state. It's preferred to use an "updater" function when defining new state which is based on the old one, now my confusion is that I have the `nextProps` parameter given to the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method, but the updater function also, gets a `props` parameter. **Which one should I use?**

Now I guess this should be specific to React 16.2; I'm guessing the introduction of the new `getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)` static method in React 16.3 should eliminate this confusion (right?)

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props, ...args) {
    super(props, ...args);
    this.state = {
      value: props.value,
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      return {
        value: (/* `nextProps or props` */).value,
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are exactly the **same** thing. If your want to access previous props, the `this.props` remains **untouched** in `componentWillReceiveProps` method.
My intuition is that `setState` doesn't fire immediately in side `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Let's consider the example below.
After first click, the `curProps` will get **0**, and `props`, `nextProps` both return **1**.

```js
class Test extends Component {
  state = {
    value: 0
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const curProps = this.props;
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      console.log('[curProps]', curProps.num);
      console.log('[props]', props.num);
      console.log('[nextProps]', nextProps.num);
      const value = prevState.value + nextProps.num;
      return {
        value
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <h4>{this.state.value}</h4>;
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    value: 0
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Test num={this.state.value} />
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Add</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ value: prevState.value + 1 }));
  };
}
```

There is the codesandbox demo https://codesandbox.io/s/zxpovzkywx

Comment: My (rudimentary) tests also reveal the same, in which both prop references contain the same value. On the other hand, there's no "official" documentation on the subject.

Comment: @ArmandoPérezMarqués In the document regards to lifecycle, it states that this event may call multiple times even without receives new props, so setState should be done conditionally. My intuition is that setState will wait until both next state and next props have been updated.